# PHP Auth Condition

Tags: php, steam

I am setting up new Steam Authentication for my website. I want it to display in a certain area, if the user is not signed in or authenticated with the Steam API I have, then it will show a link to take the to the signin page.

However, if the user is signed in, then it will simply show " Welcome Back: 'username' ". Though,

I still don't know THAT much about PHP to figure this out. Here's the code I've got for this :

```
$user = $steamprofile['personaname'];
if($user == "") {
    echo "<a href=\"/signin/\" class=\"hvr-underline-from-center\"><span>Sign In</span></a>";
} else {
    echo "Welcome back: " . $steamprofile['personaname'] . "</br>";
}
```

With the `$steamprofile['personaname']` to call the users username associated with his Steam account.

Is there something im getting wrong here?

Comment: @Matt, that'd only be appropriate if "$steamprofile['personaname']" is NULL rather than an empty string. More suitable would be "if(empty($user))". [The previous comment was deleted, though it suggested using "isset()" to check if the $user variable was blank.]

Comment: @Hiphop03199, this method works. The "if(empty($user))" method I mean. Thank's for the help :D

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure I understand enough of the question to answer the rest of it- can't tell what problem you need solved, or if there is one at all